# data fetching in real time using php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to fetch all user's name in a page from mysql and once clicked on a name their email id should be displayed in real time.

the new.php and email.php are given below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$sql="select * from users";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
?>
<a href="email.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
</a><br />

<?php

}


?>
</body>
</html>



<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="select * from users where id= '$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo $row['email'];
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lol so we should write the whole code for you. This is beyond laziness

Comment: if you have a specific thing you are stuck on, I'd be more then willing to help. However, this question is far to broad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us your efforts this far.

Comment: @artisticphoenix I have fetched all the users and can also display the particular email but thats in a new page and each time it gets refresh.

Comment: @sammaity - how do I know that, mind reading.  You need to provide some code and some input data, and some expected output data.  etc.

Comment: I can tell you, that most likely you will have to make an Ajax call to the server, on a given interval, and then using JavaScript update the client side.  The term is "Polling with Ajax and PHP"

Comment: If you already have a page showing all users you could just add a field with all emails and just hide it in a div (using display none), and when pressing on the username you show the specific email.

Comment: @artisticphoenix I have added the code. now plz tell me the procedure to make it real time

Comment: Do you know Javascript?  If not I suggest doing some tutorials on it, before attempting this.  This is not the most advanced thing out there, but without the proper foundation It will be super difficult for you to understand what is going on.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  Ya I know javascript...... bt couldnt figure out to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ( -note- I didn't test this at all, but this is the basic idea )

page.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
               function getLinks(){
                    //use ajax to get the links
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
                          document.getElementById("link_wrapper").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("GET", "get_user_email.php", true);
                    xhttp.send();
                }

                setInterval( function(){
                    //call getLinks every 5000 milliseconds
                    getLinks();
                },5000);

                //call getLinks on page load
                window.onload = getLinks;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="link_wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

get_user_email.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
    $sql="select * from users";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $html = '';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $html .= '<a href="email.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
    }

    echo $html;
```

For reference:

setInterval - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Ajax - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp